# Organize legal app route/controller

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

There are some lawyers working in different offices, they can create/update cases or 'lawsuits' for litigants.

The problem is that I'm confused how to sort them in my route ..

Should I start with lawsuits or litigants or lawyers ?

Something such: `offices/{id}/lawyers/{id}/lawsuits/{id}/`

A)

- offices -> lawyers -> lawsuits -> sessions -> judgments
- offices -> lawyers -> lawsuits -> litigants
- offices -> meetings
- articles
- courts
- judges
- users

B)

- offices -> lawsuits -> sessions -> judgments
- offices -> lawsuits -> litigants
- offices -> lawsuits -> lawyers
- offices -> meetings
- articles
- courts
- judges
- users

C)

- offices -> litigants -> lawsuits -> sessions -> judgments
- offices -> litigants -> lawsuits -> lawyers
- offices -> meetings
- articles
- courts
- judges
- users

or I have to create them all? or something else I don't know about ? is there "right way" to sort it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per looking at your question and needs of your demand, I think the best one is provided by you. Go with the first one. And yeah, just one more tip for you.

> Something such: `offices/{id}/lawyers/{id}/lawsuits/{id}/`

Don't sort them like that. Use something like this:

`{officeId}/{lawyerId}/{lawsuitId}`

And yeah. This was just as example, if possible, make them even more small like `oId` and `lId` and `lsId`.

Hope  that helps.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will go with (A), and thanks for the tip.